# Socialite Library throwing error curl_reset() undefined in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I am using socialite package with my laravel 5 project. I am hosting my site in hostgator. I have checked thrice that my php version in hostgator is 5.5.22 .

But still i am getting this error.

```
    FatalErrorException in CurlFactory.php line 69:
    Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset()
           in CurlFactory.php line 69
```

I have tried Facebook as well as Google plus login using socialite but in both cases when redirects to my controller/function it throws this error.

Please help me. What can be possible errors

My Auth controller functions are

```
public function getFacebookLogin(){
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }
    public function getHandleFbLogin(){
        //echo "hey";
         $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
         print_r($user);
    }

    public function getGoogleLogin(){
        return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect();
    }
    public function getHandleGpLogin(){
    echo "hey";
         $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user();
         print_r($user);
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

I am very new to Stackoverflow. I also got stucked in this, so I did the following :-

Go to 
/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php

line no. 69 and replace

> curl_reset($resource);

```
 with
```

> ```
>         curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
>         curl_setopt($resource, CURLOPT_POST, false);
> ```

Comment: I solved this problem by changing .htaccess file in public folder. just added at top  AddHandler application/x-httpd-php55 .php

Comment: The cleanest way to deal with this issue is to update to PHP5.5. Otherwise, Harneet solution is right.